# Have light cast on an object visible, but the the object to be invisible

Tags: light, visibility, emission

[image][image]Does anyone know how to achieve the effect of having a light cast upon an object, yet for that object to be invisible when rendered, yet the light that is cast upon the object is still visible?

I've tried experimenting with the Light Path Node, Mix Shader Node, The Object Properties/Visibility Tab, but with no success - it is an obscure thing to ask for I suppose...

If this isn't clear I can rephrase!

I'm working in 2.90.1 and in Cycles

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a light threshold? And, which rendering engine do you want to use?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm fairly new to blender - I want to render in cycles, what is a light threshold?

Comment: threshold would be bacause, if no light all is dark and if even very little light, there is light. Or is the lamp a spot?

Comment: I'm wanting to get the effect of the light on the object, but the object itself to remain invisible

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images, or even a rough sketch. Some people (like me) have rather bad imagination :).

Comment: Hi, I've posted an image of the setup - thanks for your help! I suppose I could always apply an image texture of a soft blue gradient spot with an alpha channel as an image texture?

Comment: The second picture shows a rough experiment with alpha image texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you want it in Cycles, though you can do it using Eevee:

[image]

The node setting:

[image]

The key point is to use *"diffuse"* and *"shader to rgb"* (the left part). This is some kind of preshading that allow to test the light intensity. This result is then tuned through a colorramp to mix between the lighted and transparent parts.

[image]

Comment: Incredible! I don't know how you figured it out but thank you!